# Slicing: When passing derived as reference to base, the base references loses data?

Tags: c++, debugging, inheritance, reference, casting

EDIT: Completely restated question:  Answer below:

I am having problems when passing a derived type as a reference to the base type.  It seems that the referenced object has it's data cleared/reinitialized before/after being casted from Derived to Base.

I thought that when passing a Derived instance to a function that acccepts the parameter as a reference to the Base object (Derived -> Base&), the referenced Base instance will stay consistent in memory to the Derived object, unless passed as value.

I have the Base class, a state of data that is considered 'read-only':

```
class ReadonlyText
{
protected:
   int m_Length;
   char* m_String;
public:
   ReadonlyText() m_Length(0), m_String(0) {} // a null base
   ReadonlyText(const char* str) : m_Length(0), m_String(str)
   {
       do
       {
           m_Length++;
       }while(*ptr++);
   }
   ReadonlyText(const ReadonlyText& copy) : m_Length(copy.m_Length), m_String(copy.m_String)
   {
   }
   virtual ~Readonly() {};

   ... virtual nonsense
};  // lets not forget the semicolon
```

Now I have the Derived class, that is writable:

```
class Text
{
public:
    Text() : m_Length(1), m_String(Memory::New<char>(m_Length)) {}
    Text(const ReadonlyText& copy) : m_Length(copy.m_Length), m_String(Memory::New<char>(m_Length))
    {
        for(whole i = 0; i < m_Length; ++i)
            m_String[i] = copy.m_String[i];
    }
    Text(const Text& copy) : m_Length(copy.m_Length), m_String(Memory::New<char>(m_Length))
    {
        for(whole i = 0; i < m_Length; ++i)
            m_String[i] = copy.m_String[i];
    }

    virtual ~Text()
    {
         if((m_Length != 0 && m_String != null<char>::value)) 
         {
              Memory::Delete<Char>(m_String);
              m_Length = 0;
              m_String = null<Char>::value;
         }
    }

    // operator==(ReadonlyText&)
    // operator!=(ReadonlyText&)
    // operator==(Text&)
    // operator!=(Text&)
    // operator=(Text&)
    // operator=(ReadonlyText&)
    // I don't have time to format all these functions for best visibility in SO, 
    // I assure you that all these functions are implemented properly

    // THE PROBLEM occurs in any function with ReadonlyText&, say:
    Text operator+(const ReadonlyText& rhs)
    {
        //...
        // Before the function begins, 'rhs.m_String' == 0x0
        // see case below 
    }
};

// ...

int main(...)
{
    Text t1 = Text("hello");
    Text t2 = Text("world");

    // in the debugger, at this point, both t1 && t2 '.m_String' is valid
    // as "hello" and "world" respectively
    // but when stepping into:

    Text t3 = t1 + t2; // the function described above...

    // ...which is t1.operator+(t2) // where t2 is passed as ReadonlyText&
    // the debugger shows:
    // t1.m_String == "hello"
    // t2.m_String == 0x0   -- this should be "world"

    // since no copy construction is occuring, (passing as reference), then
    // the data should be consistent with the derived type, right?

}
```

What happens is, in operator+, I attempt to access 'rhs.m_String', which should be evaluated to "world", but for some reason has been instanced as a new ReadonlyText instead of being passed as a reference??

Further, the program does not crash with any messages; no segmentation fault or error.  Instead, it just completely quits, as if the application ran smoothly until end of main?

There isn't much more going on than what I describe here.  Memory::New and Memory::Delete encapsulate memory operations (new and delete) so that New returns a pointer based on the size of the template typename and the given length.  Delete just ensures that proper destruction of the pointers.  And null is a structure that ensures consitent null values for typenames:

```
//class Memory:

template<typename T> static T* New(whole length = 1)
{
    return (T*)(operator new (length * sizeof(T)));
}
template<typename T> static void Delete(T* pointer)
{
    operator delete (pointer);
}

// null struct
template<typename T>
struct null
{
    static constexpr T* value = 0x0;
}
```

THE REAL PROBLEM:

<_< I forgot to remove the Derived members (which are m_Length and m_String) when redesigning the class hierarchy.  So the Derived instance had members that were masking the Base members.  Long story short, when something doesn't make sense, it's probably your fault:

```
class Base
{
    ...
protected:
    int m_Length;
    char* m_String;
};

class Derived : public virtual Base
{
    ...
protected:  // xD WTH was I hoping to do here???
    int m_Length;
    char* m_String;
};
```

There should be a compiler feature for inheritance that prevents masking, but until then be careful...just be careful.  Thanks all to tried helping me, and for those who backed out.

Comment: Why post such shoddy pseudo-code. Spend the extra five minutes and produce proper, clean, minimal code that we can compile and that exemplifies your problem.

Comment: An extra five minutes will turn into hours.  These classes are not as simple as I am portraying them to be.  The operations span across hundreds of lines and are organized into many files. I only post the problem, recently added and untested.  I see where you stand though... +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a part of your actual code then I suspect you have an error in your derived class, since `m_Data` belong to your `Base` class you can't initialize it directly in your `Derived` class and since it is `private` to `Base` then you can't access it at all, then I assume you also have a member `m_Data` in your `Derived` and that member hide the `m_Data` of `Base`, so what you see in the debugger is `m_Data` of the `Derived` and what you see in the function is `m_Data` of the `Base` that is `nullptr` since it is initialized using default constructor of `Base`

Comment: I'm sorry, m_Data is protected.  My code compiles, and executes, but crashes when I pass a Derived instance as a Base (& reference).  For some reason the casted Base& has m_Data evaluated to 0x0.  The base class does not mess with m_Data (at all), only read only operations.  And Derived constructs m_Data and deletes m_Data.  Following through with the debugger, nothing fishy happens until I pass by Base reference.  The Derived copy-ctors do nothing strange either (they are not even called) when passing as Base&.

Comment: Even if `m_Data` be protected you can't initialize it in the `Derived` since it does not belong to `Derived` directly and it should initialized by `Base`, so if you can compile `Derived() : m_Data(new)` then you have something wrong because normally you should get an error from this initialization

Comment: Really?  Because the compiler is compiling the code without error.  I declare the Derived class with : public virtual Base, so shouldn't Base members with protected and above be visible to the derived instance??

Comment: OMG!!! You were right!  You were all so very right!  I really thought I removed the few lines of protected members from my Derived class after I redesigned.  It's funny, because I thought I should have gotten errors too, but since I didn't, I assumed I was just doing a good job. Turns out I was masking the Base members with the Derived members. This class hierarchy used involve only one class, the readable/writable Derived type, but I figured I could make use of read-only, so after implementation, I FORGOT to remove the Derived members. Which are now just masking the inherited ones.THANK YOU!